# Working with optionals elegantly

Tags: swift

I have a property in a class returning the `total / count`. Both `total` and `count` are optionals. Is there a more elegant way of checking that they have values than this:

```
var equalAmount: Float? { 
    if total != nil, count != nil {
        return total! / Float(count!)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all consider to use non-optionals. In most numeric cases optionals are not really necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Just about any way is more elegant than using force-unwrap. Take your pick between:

`if let`: closest to your current design

```
if let total = total, let count = count {
    return total / Float(count)
} else {
    return nil
}
```

`guard let`: less indentation

```
guard let total = total, let count = count else { return nil }
return total / Float(count)
```

or `map` and `flatMap`: for a one-liner

```
return total.flatMap { total in count.map { total / Float($0) } }
```

Comment: no need to use underscore when using guard. You can still access the original total property if needed using `self.total`

Comment: @LeoDabus I wanted to make the answer a bit more universal, since it used to be that if the optional you were unwrapping was a local variable rather than a property, shadowing it with `guard let` would cause a compilation error. However, I just tried it in Swift 4 and it doesn't seem to do that anymore, so they must have changed this behavior at some point. I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var equalAmount: Float? { 
    guard let totalUnwrapped = total,
          let countUnwrapped = count
          else {return nil}
    return totalUnwrapped / countUnwrapped
}
```

This would be my approach. I use guard let when you really need the variables to continue the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `guard` `let` to unwrap the values if the condition in the guard is not true then the else part will return to the function and this will not execute the other in it. `guard` is more preferable in compare to `if let` statements to check the unwrap values and to return immediately  :

```
var equalAmount: Float? { 
    guard let newTotal = total else {
         return nil
    }
    guard let newCount = count else {
         return nil
    }

return newTotal/newCount

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Ternary Conditional Operator:

```
var equalAmount: Float? { 
    return total != nil && count != nil ? total! / Float(count!) : nil
}
```

Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html